# Prefetching javascript file does not execute it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am prefetching a javascript file. I can see in the network tab that the file has been retrieved. But, the file itself is not being executed and i can't see an alert.

Here is minimal example:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <link rel="prefetch" href="alert.js">
</body>
</html>
```

**alert.js**

```
alert('hello world')
```

---

When I am importing the file with script tag like this, the file do get executed.

```
<script src="alert.js"></script>
```

How is it possible to execute a prefetched javascript file?

- using chrome 63.

Comment: `link rel="prefetch"` is meant to fetch resources which will be used on the *next* page, not the current page. Therefore JavaScript is not executed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to execute a prefetched javascript file?

By adding a script element pointing to its URL.

The purpose of prefetching is to download some data into the browser's cache and do *nothing else*.

This makes it available *quickly* when the time comes to load it.